# Reference on Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, sobolev-spaces

While reading about calculus of variations I stumbled upon the Sobolev spaces $W^{k,p}(\Omega;\mathbb{R}^n)$ of order $k$ weakly differentiable functions with $p$ integrable derivatives, and codomain $\mathbb{R}^n$ instead of $\mathbb{R}$. Do you have any reference where definitions and properties about those spaces are provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the best books for a whole course about Sobolev Spaces is “Giovanni Leoni - [*A first course in Sobolev Spaces*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/A_First_Course_in_Sobolev_Spaces/qoA8DwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=leoni%20sobolev&pg=PR4&printsec=frontcover)”

Another book is “Adams - [*Sobolev Spaces*](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Sobolev_Spaces/R5A65Koh-EoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=leoni%20sobolev&printsec=frontcover)”.

If you are interested in Sobolev Spaces from the point of view of PDEs then:

- Brezis’ book *[Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Functional_Analysis_Sobolev_Spaces_and_P/GAA2XqOIIGoC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=brezis%20functional%20analysis&printsec=frontcover)* (mainly chapter 8 of the second edition)
- Evans’ book *[Partial Differential Equations](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Partial_Differential_Equations/Xnu0o_EJrCQC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=evans%20partial%20differential%20equations&printsec=frontcover)* (mainly chapter 5 of the second edition).

Just since you told me you are interested in Sobolev spaces from the calculus of variations (dark) side, let me point out we all can't wait - no joke - for the publication of Fonseca and Leoni's new book, *[Modern Methods in the Calculus of Variations: Sobolev Spaces](http://giovannileoni.weebly.com/publications.html)*, in preparation, accepted for publication by Springer.

Comment: Nice! I will check it out

Comment: May I also ask, out of curiosity, why calculus of variations is the dark side from which to approach Sobolev spaces?

Comment: "The dark side of the Force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural."
―Darth Sidious, to Anakin Skywalker (It was just my distinction between the indirect and the direct method of the calculus of variations - Euler and Lagrange would be very surprised by the technique of finding the minimum in a "larger" space and then study if this minimum has some regularity properties :) )

Answer (score 2):

You may also have a look into

E. Lieb, M. Loss: [Analysis](https://books.google.at/books?id=Eb_7oRorXJgC&dq=lieb%20and%20loss&hl=de&source=gbs_navlinks_s)